# Fallo al retornar 0

Tags: c++

El programa consiste únicamente en introducir un nombre, y si este se encuentra en el fichero, mostrar un menú. En caso contrario el menú no es mostrado y se finaliza el programa mediante la función fin() que retorna en 0.

No obstante aunque el nombre no se halle en el fichero, el menú se muestra.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

bool localizacionJugador(char apodo);
void menu();
int fin();


int main()
{
    ofstream ficheroSalida;
    ficheroSalida.open("db2.txt");
    ficheroSalida << "a";
    ficheroSalida.close();

    char apodo;
    cout << "Introduzca su nombre:";
    cin >> apodo;
    localizacionJugador(apodo);
    menu();
}


bool localizacionJugador(char apodo)
{
    char c;
    bool encontrado=false;
    fstream ficheroEntrada;
    ficheroEntrada.open("db2.txt");
    if(ficheroEntrada.is_open())
    {
        while(!ficheroEntrada.eof() && c!=apodo)
        {
            ficheroEntrada.get(c);
        }
        encontrado=c==apodo;
        if(encontrado==true)
        {
            cout << "Usuario encontrado"<<endl<<endl;
        }else
        {
            cout << "Usuario no encontrado";
            fin();
        }
    }else
    {
        cout << "Fichero no encontrado";
        fin();
    }
    ficheroEntrada.close();
    return encontrado;
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "Este es el menu";
}

int fin()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: return no sale del programa. sale de la funcion.

Comment: Que menú te refieres "Press any key to continue"?

Comment: El menú seria 'void menu()', que lo unico que contiene es un cout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú código:

```
localizacionJugador( apodo );
menu( );
```

¿ Donde compruebas si lo has encontrado o no ? Tal y como está, el menú se mostrá **siempre**. Te falta **comprobar el valor devuelto por la función**:

```
if( localizacionJugador( apodo ) ) {
  menu( );
}
```

Aparte de eso, esas cosas que haces, pasar `apodo` como un `char` ... los `char` contienen *caracteres individuales*, **no** *cadenas*. Te sugiero que revises la parte del código relevante.